# Can I use Wolfram Mathematica fonts in XeTeX / LuaTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, unicode-math, wolfram-mathematica

Wolfram *Mathematica* comes with full (?) set of math fonts. Is it possible to use these fonts in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX? I mean something like

```
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[range=...]{Mathematica1}
\setmathfont[range=...,Bold]{Mathematica1b}
\setmathfont[range=...,???]{Mathematica1m}
\setmathfont[range=...,???]{Mathematica1mb}
\setmathfont[range=...]{Mathematica2}
. . .
\setmathfont[range=...]{Mathematica7}
```

Comment: `unicode-math` needs OpenType Math fonts. I don't think Mathematica provides those.

Comment: @Garamir: Mathematica comes with True Type fonts. Shouldn't unicode-math work with True Type?

Comment: @Joseph Wright: I guess that MS Word works with single math fonts (all math symbols, operators) in single file. Word has no mechanism (at least I don't know such) to incorporate several font files simulteneously, but `unicode-math` provides such mechanism through `range` option of `\setmathfont`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Math typesetting is complex, and needs a lot of structures inside the font. OpenType math fonts have these, but TrueType ones don't. I suspect that Mathematica relies on 'knowing' details of the fonts, in the same way that traditional TeX math fonts are made up of several files with a known relationship (to TeX). So you won't be able to use these fonts with LuaTeX, or I suspect with the Word 2007/2010 equation editor (which also uses OpenType).