# Problem with installing Wolfram Mathematica fonts in TeX Live

Tags: fonts, wolfram-mathematica

I've been trying to install the Wolfram Mathematica fonts in my installation of TeX Live 2011, running under OS X Lion. I used a mangled version of [these instructions](http://blog.spitzenpfeil.org/wordpress/2011/02/07/getting-mathematica-fonts-to-work-with-pdflatex/). I placed the files in `/usr/local/texlive/2011basic/texmf-local/`, and didn't muck around with Ghostscript; I don't use it.

Then I add `\usepackage{wrisym}` to the pre-amble of my document, and I was hoping that that would be enough to install the fonts. This seems to have helped somewhat. Before I'd moved any font files around, I was getting the error

```
\!pdfTeXerror: pdflatex (file Math1Bold.pfa): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading

==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

A fatal error occured, log file is in foobar.log
```

I'm guessing that means that it can't find the font file for `Math1Bold`, the first font it looks for, which makes sense, because I hadn't installed any font files at this point. However, when I had moved all of the font files into place, as per the above instructions, I was getting the error:

```
\!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file Math5Mono-Bold.pfa): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading

==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

A fatal error occured, log file is in foobar.log
```

Presumably this means that there's something wrong with this `.pfa` file. I've had a look at it, but I can't see anything that's obviously wrong. I've downloaded the file several times to ensure I didn't just have a corrupted version of this particular file, but no joy there.

Does anybody have any suggestions for how I can get `Math5Mono-Bold` (and any other problem files that crop up) working, or at least make my TeX installation forget it's there so that I can make PDFs and use the Mathematica fonts?

---

### Notes

I know there might be a way of using XeTeX or LuaTeX to configure the fonts, but I've never used either of them before, and [this TeX.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30638/can-i-use-wolfram-mathematica-fonts-in-xetex-luatex) question makes it sound like there might not be much point in trying.

This is a minimal *not*-working example that triggers the second error message above:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrisym,amsmath}

\begin{document}

Foo bar. %
\begin{equation*}
    2+2=5.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I've uploaded the log from this example here: http://cl.ly/0k0P2L051v290e3m1m28.

Comment: I checked the fonts in the zip linked on the website you mentioned (http://phong.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/~kuska/wri_texmf_4.2.zip). It doesn't contain fonts named "Math5...", the font names there start with with "Mathematica...", these names are also used by the map-files. So probably you have another map which gets in the way.

Answer (score 7):

I'm the one who wrote the 'manual' you've linked to.

I've just tested your LaTeX code and it compiles just fine on my system. Suffice to say that I installed these fonts according to my manual - on more than one system. Maybe you forgot a critical step.

Please also note that I did not use the `texmf-local` directory. It should work as far as I can tell, but who knows...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Hmm, ok, thanks Robert. I’ll have to go back and have another look. I suspect the problem lies in my “mangling”.

Comment: What's the difference for TeXLive on Mac OS X: use (1) robert's method linked above or (2) Kuska's method in mysymdoc.pdf from  the Mathematica 8's SystemFiles/IncludeFiles/TeX/texmf/doc?

(1) explicitly refers to linux, not OS X. (2) uses Mathematica files only, but Kuska refers only to MikTeX on Windows or teTeX on Unix.

Also, (1) says to edit the .map files to change .pfb to .pfa (the Wolfram-supplied Type 1 font files use .pfa for their extensions).
Is that better than just changing the extensions of the Type 1 font files themselves to .pfb?

Comment: @robert: do your instructions, cited above, use the Mathematica version 4.2 fonts (with names like `Mathematica5`) or the newer fonts (with names like `Math5`?

Comment: (Still totally confused!) How does one use the newer versions of the Mathematica fonts instead of the older version 4.2 fonts?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have access to anything later than V4.2 - and luckily I don't need it.