# How use Mathematica fonts with LaTeX - which method?

Tags: fonts, wolfram-mathematica

I want to be able to use Mathematica fonts with LaTeX. I find two sets of instructions for this:

1. Robert's post [there](http://blog.spitzenpfeil.org/wordpress/2011/02/07/getting-mathematica-fonts-to-work-with-pdflatex/)
2. Kuska's instructions in `mysymdoc.pdf`, a file in the Mathematica 8 folder `SystemFiles/IncludeFiles/TeX/texmf/doc`.

Method (1) explicitly assumes one is using linux, although [robert indicates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46002/problem-with-installing-wolfram-mathematica-fonts-in-tex-live) the method should work for OS X.

Method (2) uses files that are distributed with Mathematica for OS X, but Kuska refers only to MikTeX on Windows and teTeX on Unix.

Which works with TeXLive 2011 under OS X?

Also, method (1) says to edit the two `.map`files so as to change `.pfb` to `.pfa` (presumably because the Wolfram-supplied Type 1 font files have extension `.pfa`.

Why edit the `.map` files like that instead of changing the extensions of the font files themselves to `.pfb`?

Comment: Method (1) is *not* good for TeX Live 2011.

Comment: What about considering the [`mathematica` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathematica) which provides support for virtual fonts?

Comment: I thought robert said his files included the mathematica package, by Kuska, that you cite. And Kuska's package is, I believe, the same thing that's supplied with Mathematica itself, in the `SystemFiles/IncludeFiles/TeX` folder.

Answer (score 10):

The instructions you mention are rather outdated.

1. Modify `wolfram.map` to have `.pfa` instead of `.pfb` (to reflect the format of the font files) and remove all from `Janson Text` onwards, as those fonts are not provided.
2. Copy `wolfram.map` to

   ```
   /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/map/dvips/wolfram/wolfram.map
   ```
3. Copy all subfolders from `texmf/fonts` (`afm/wolfram` …) to the corresponding folders in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts`.
4. Copy the directory `texmf/tex/latex/wolfram` to `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/wolfram`
5. Copy `texmf/doc/wolfram` to `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/doc/latex/wolfram`
6. Run `mktexlsr` so that TeX Live will know about these files
7. Run `updmap-sys --enable Map=wolfram.map`
8. Enjoy

All steps from 2 to 7 should be done as Administrator (prefix the commands with `sudo`, typing the Administrator's password when requested)

Note that the `7z` archive linked to in the blog article seems to be corrupt, while the `.zip` file is good.

---

### Update

From TeX Live 2013 onwards, it's better to add the line

```
Map wolfram.map
```

to the file

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c/updmap.cfg
```

(also requires Administrator privileges) and subsequently run

```
updmap-sys
```

without options. This replaces step 7 above.

Comment: The .zip file contents, robert says, is a subset of what's in the 7z file. In any case, I was able to unarchive the 7z file without any error message.

Comment: I keep all personal additions, including fonts inside `~/Library/texmf`. I'm the only user, with an admin account. 

Should that not work? Is it essential, instead, to put `wolfram.map` (for my setup) in `~/Library/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/wolfram/`?

E.g., I copied `wolfram.map` to `~/Library/texmf/fonts/dvips/config`. And I added the entry `Map wolfram.map #localtexmf/dvips/config/wolfram.map` to file `~/Library/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg` before running `mktexlsr` and `updmap-sys`.

Comment: @murray What's most important is not using `updmap` that may create problems in using fonts when they are updated via `tlmgr`.

Comment: I am using Mathematica 9.0.1: I copied all necessary files in steps 2-5, and successfully got 6 to work.  At step 7 I got error `Unknown option: enable-map`.  Any ideas?  Would it work if I just skipped this step?

Comment: I tried to compile my LaTeX document with `\usepackage{wrisym}` but it failed: `mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for Mathematica1`.  So clearly I'm doing something wrong.  Any ideas?

Comment: @QuantumDot `updmap-sys --enable Map=wolfram map` should work. I'll fix the code.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, it now runs marginally better: But after 4 lines of output (including `resetting $HOME$ value`), it gives me the error: `updmap: invalid mapType map at /usr/texbin/updmap line 1470.`  This seems to be an excessive amount of trouble for something so simple.

Comment: @QuantumDot What TeX distribution are you running?

Comment: @QuantumDot If the Mathematica font distribution is corrupt, it's not a fault of the TeX system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16722/discussion-between-quantumdot-and-egreg).

Comment: @egreg Sorry again to bother you: I've noticed that in addition to giving me the mathematica input font, `\usepackage{wrisym}` also replaces the default font of the body text, and of the normal equation environment.  I am struggling with trying to restore the main body and equation font to Computer Modern while keeping the Mathematica font available for the document.  I would be really grateful if you could point me in the right direction!

Comment: @QuantumDot Surely `wrisym` changes the math fonts, which is its main job. It also changes the default text font family to `ptm` (Times). You don't need to load `wrisym`, but it's not really clear what you mean by “keeping the Mathematica font” available.

Comment: @egreg Wait; wasn't the whole point of adding `\usepackage[uprightmonomath]{wrisym}` to get the Mathematica font?  If I take that line out, I lose the Mathematica font, so must keep it.  I guess my question is how to restore the default text font family to Computer Modern?

Comment: @QuantumDot Add `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{cmr}` after loading `wrisym`.

Comment: I just got a new computer with Yosemite, installed TexLive successfully, followed all your steps successfully, but TeX still had problems creating fonts.  According to https://tug.org/mactex/yosemite.html, Ghostscript is broken in Yosemite.  Is Ghostscript needed to make these fonts?

Comment: @QuantumDot Not sure why you get this problem; never tested on Yosemite, sorry.

Comment: For my own reference, running `sudo -H updmap-sys --enable Map wolfram.map` at the very end (step 9) seems to make it all work in Yosemite.

Comment: For my own reference, From TeX Live 2017 onwards, the files should be copied to `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/...`.  Also the line `Map wolfram.map` should be added to `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg` (not sure about this one... why in a different folder??)

Comment: @QuantumDot No, never copy anything in the main tree.

Comment: Then what is the correct way to make it work?  I couldn’t make it work using the older method.

Comment: @QuantumDot The `texmf-local` way is still the right one.