# Local font installation problems

Tags: fonts, pdftex, texlive, mtpro

Recently I tried to reinstall the MathTimePro II fonts in my local `texmf` directory. I already have Lucida fonts installed which works fine. So I carefully copied all the relevant files/folders to the directories, added the new Map entry in the local updmap.cfg file and executed `texhash`/`mktexlsr` and `updmap-sys`. However my new font does not work, I get the following error:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/../texmf-local/tex/latex/mtpro2/mtpro2.sty)
(./MTPro2 LaTeX test.aux)
[1{/Users/hesam/Library/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/
map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2] [3] (./MTPro2 LaTeX test.aux)
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 4+0/600 --dpi
2400 mt2exf gsftopk: fatal: map file `cid-base.map' not found.
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for mt2exf. mktexpk:
perhaps mt2exf is missing from the map file. kpathsea: Appending font
creation commands to missfont.log.  )

!pdfTeX error: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file mt2exf): Font mt2exf at 2400
not foun d

==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

It knows where to find `mtpro2.sty` in the local directory but can't find the fonts which are basically next door!

I have gone through a lot of online remedies but none have helped. I even restored the `pdftex` to an older version and started all over. The problem seems to be that the `pdftex.map` file does not have the fonts despite there being a map entry for mtpro2.

**PS:** I am using TeXShop/TeXLive (2011) on OS X 10.6.

Comment: At first you shouldn't change updmap.cfg directly. In TeXLive you should use `updmap-sys --enable Map=XXXX` (or `updmap --enable Map=XXXX`). At second: The path of `pdftex.map` sounds a bit as if it is a local map generated by `updmap` (without `-sys`). Rerun `updmap-sys` (eventually with the option `--verbose` and check if it actually change the `pdftex.map`.

Comment: I added the map entry to my 'local' updmap.cfg, I did use updmap-sys as well and finally the option you recommend does not exist.

Comment: Did you run `updmap-sys` and checked if it actually changed the `pdftex.map` (look e.g. a the file date)?

Comment: Yes everytime I run updmap-sys, pdftex.map gets rewritten (it also says the same in updmap-sys output: "Files generated: ....").

Comment: I did't ask if one pdftex.map is generated but if the pdftex.map *mentioned in the log* gets rewritten. Check the one in `Users/hesam/Library/...`.

Comment: That one has not changed. But when I deleted it, it went back to using the one that changes. When I deleted both pdftex does not work anymore.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The key is here:

```
[1{/Users/hesam/Library/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
```

You have, on some occasion, run `updmap` (not `updmap-sys`) and your TeX system uses the generated `pdftex.map` sitting in your personal tree.

Remove that file, so that the TeX system will use the global `pdftex.map` file.

To be on the safe side, after removing the file run from the Terminal the following commands:

```
sudo tlmgr generate updmap
sudo updmap-sys --enable-map <name>.map
```

(Change `<name>` into the correct name of the file in the MTPro distribution.)

In any case, adding the line

```
\pdfmapfile{=<name>.map}
```

before `\begin{document}` should make pdfTeX able to find the correct map file.

Comment: I removed that one but it started using the other pdftex.map which is in usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap. But this produces the same exact problem. Then I deleted this map file as well and now pdftex does not work anymore.

Comment: @Hesam Of course, if you delete the global `pdftex.map`, `pdftex` won't be able to run. Try following the instructions I added.

Comment: In case of "Unknown option: enable-map", see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51704/how-use-mathematica-fonts-with-latex-which-method for example with `updmap-sys --enable Map=_font_.map`

Comment: Saved my day! I removed the `pdftex.map` file in the `updmap` sub-folder mentioned in the log and then rerun `sudo-updmap-sys --enable Map=...` it worked. Thanks!

Comment: In my case I purposefully ran `tlmgr` in  user mode. In order to have new fonts working I then had to run `updmap -user` as otherwise I had an error `mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for ...` with the missing font and `updmap-sys` would only update the global files.

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by [@jon in this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171868/no-pdf-output-in-auctex?noredirect=1#comment397314_171868)  purge latex or all the version of latex entirely from your system and install again that did the job for me. After spending some time trying in vain for hours to get latex use the right updmap file, reinstall latex completely.

If you face the same problem I suggest [this answer which guide you towards completely removing latex from your system.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95502/35238). Make sure to search and delete any file related to /texlive/year/ before installing latex again.

Comment: If you really have files under `/texlive/YYYY/ then there is not something wrong with just your TeX installation. There is something serious wrong with your operating system. I assume you mean `~/.texliveYYYY/`  or something in your home `Library` (MacTeX) . If so, deleting those files and NEVER USING `updmap` AGAIN is the key. There is no reason to reinstall TeX and doing so is completely pointless as it will have no effect at all. Please read http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i if you are still around.

Comment: Where did I say that the files were under /texlive/YYYY/?. Don't assume things too quickly :-). I provided a solution that worked for me at the time. I just shared this knowledge. Very good  for everyone if you have a better one.

Comment: Hardly an assumption. I simply read your answer. You said `Make sure to search and delete any file related to /texlive/year/ before installing latex again.`You might also have meant something like `/usr/local/texlive/YYYY`. Still very different from `/texlive/YYYY`, though.

Comment: Removing `texlive/YYYY`, `texlive/texmf-local` and some other folders, and then re-installing MacTeX worked for me. I had another error afterwards, but installing getnonfreefonts resolved that.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**

Everything below is wrong. To understand why, please read: [Why shouldn't I use getnonfreefonts to install additional fonts? Why shouldn't I use updmap when installing or removing fonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i)

Note that the script I originally used came from [this post](https://kieranhealy.org/blog/archives/2012/11/10/installing-minion-pro/). *DO NOT USE this original script*. A safer and updated approach to installing Minion Pro can be found [here](http://www.clarkdonley.com/blog/2015-03-07-installing-minionpro-for-latex-on-mac-os-x-yosemite.html).

---

**OLD/IGNORE**

I had a similar error when install MinionPro:

```
Library/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./minionpro-test.aux)
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 0+545/600 --dpi 545 MinionPro-Regular-Base-aa
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for MinionPro-Regular-Base-aa.
mktexpk: perhaps MinionPro-Regular-Base-aa is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
```

<s>I found that `updmap --enable MixedMap MinionPro.map` was not sufficient. After reinstalling multiple times, I found that another run of `updmap` at the end did the trick.</s>

```
   updmap --enable MixedMap MinionPro.map
   updmap
```

Comment: This is not correct. Minion Pro does not provide a `MixedMap`. This is for fonts which include source and scalable fonts. It is not a 'trick' to workaround whatever other problem you were experiencing. Note that if you are using TeX Live, you should NOT use `updmap` EVER unless you have absolutely no choice. If you have absolutely no choice, consider using a different font configuration rather than using this.

Comment: Please read http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i.