# How to remove everything related to TeX Live for fresh install on Ubuntu?

Tags: installing, texlive, ubuntu

How can I remove everything that is related to TeX Live from my Ubuntu 12.04? I first used the backport packages from `ppa:texlive-backports/ppa` and later the manual install via [`install-tl-unx.tar.gz`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html). Somehow, everything screwed up, so I want to remove everything to start from scratch.

I want to get a recent TeX Live with Biber support and extended font support, i.e. support for Source Sans Pro.

What to do?

Comment: how about `rm -rf /usr/local/texlive/2012` and `rm -rf ~/.texlive2012`?

Comment: For new versions, not from the official repository, consider installing on `/opt`.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Try the following commands, one after another. If you progress, respective folders may already be deleted:

1. `sudo apt-get purge texlive*`
2. `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/texlive/*` and `rm -rf ~/.texlive*`
3. `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/texmf`
4. `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/texmf`
5. `sudo rm -rf /etc/texmf`
6. `sudo apt-get remove tex-common --purge`
7. `rm -rf ~/.texlive`
8. `find -L /usr/local/bin/ -lname /usr/local/texlive/*/bin/* | xargs -r rm`

   This finds all the files in `/usr/local/bin` which point to a location within `/usr/local/texlive/*/bin/*` and removes them; because we’ve already deleted all of `/usr/local/texlive`, these are dead links. To see which files are being deleted, replace `xargs rm` with `xargs -t rm` (or `tee` off to a log file, or whatever).

---

#### Update

In case that - after the last command (8.) - your terminal returns something like this

```
rm: cannot remove '/usr/local/bin/deweb': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/usr/local/bin/dviconcat': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/usr/local/bin/pkfix-helper': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/usr/local/bin/ulqda': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/usr/local/bin/kpsereadlink': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/usr/local/bin/bibmradd': Permission denied
...
...
...
```

if you know what you're doing, you can add `sudo` between the pipe and `xargs rm`, so that it becomes

```
find -L /usr/local/bin/ -lname /usr/local/texlive/*/bin/* | sudo xargs rm
```

or, to be more careful and also more thorough, follow the steps of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257042/117274), which worked for [me](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117274/thymaro).

#### Update 2

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36618260.) to solve the issue of `rm: missing operand` when running (8.)

Comment: That is fine.  Without that command, an artifact from debian installation is left over.  This isn't a problem for 2012 but it cause a headache for me when installing 2013.

Comment: So, I have just gone through the process, took me about 20+min, just others can do it, when they've got the time to do so. Since I ran `sudo apt-get remove texlive-full` before some of the commands did nothing, e.g. `ls -ltrh >/tmp/rmlist`. Hopefully everything ready for fresh install.

Comment: This is why I find it hard to like Linux. With Windows, I click one Uninstall button and I'm done. With Linux, it takes half an hour of command line typing :-/

Comment: @mcbetz Very useful answer. For total vim illiterates like me it should be noted that: To insert 'rm' command before each line in the file `rmcmd` you will need to type `vim rmcmd` and then `:%s/^/ rm-rv /`. In the answer above `:` is missing before `%s...`. It caused me many headaches.

Comment: Why is there anything in `/usr/local/bin`? Certainly `apt` ought not put stuff there. For sure, the TeX Live installer doesn't put anything there. (That puts *everything* in `/usr/local/texlive/`. Some of the others are presumably the distro spraying files.

Comment: what is the arev file? I don't have that...

Comment: Is this still valid for 2016 also?

Comment: @Nate Actually, that's exactly why people use Linux and blame Windows for lacking a decent terminal. ;) I do not want to bring up the old Linux-Windows war, but it's the shortcoming of "texlive" installing system, not Linux.

Comment: @mcbetz @thymaro Thanks for the answer and edit. However, `find -L /usr/local/bin/ -lname /usr/local/texlive/*/bin/* | xargs rm` yields the following error: `rm: missing operand`. I am not sure why this is happening?

Comment: @DavidC. I don't really understand any of it from just looking at it. I'm just an ape following recipes I find online. Sorry for being of little help on this one. Have you tried the `-t` option mentioned above? What does it return?

Comment: @DavidC. @thymaro I have the same problem and the `-t` option doesn't make a difference, the appearance of the xarg syntax has changed. I understand that step 8 is a check so it doesn't seem so serious not to be able to access it. Anyway I leave testimony of it to be able to correct the answer in the future.

Comment: I've fixed your problems, @DavidC. That was an old version of the bash command, which I've edited.

Comment: Possibly also  `~/.texmf-var`

Comment: @Kyle I have the same issue that DavidC had. How can I fix it? I don't see any fix here.

Comment: @eng.mrgh it's a suggested edit you can find [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/176109).

Comment: If symlinks were added in `/usr/local/bin/` when installing vanilla TeXLive, step 8 can be achieved with `tlmgr path remove`, likely needing `sudo`, *before* uninstalling. This is also done when calling `tlmgr remove --all` as @mygod suggests in his answer.

Answer (score 33):

Martin Betz's answer is great but it is missing one line that caused issue on my machine (Ubuntu 13.04).  This was for upgrading from 2012 to 2013.

After 5., run `sudo apt-get remove tex-common --purge`.  If not, you may have the problem I faced here [Does TeXLive2013 need any special install instructions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120120/does-texlive2013-need-any-special-install-instructions/120285#120285)

Comment: I added your extra line to my answer. I hope you are okay with that!

Answer (score 11):

I think you should

1. remove all packages (via ubuntu's package manager and `install-tl` too)
2. remove `/usr/{,local}/share/texmf*`
3. remove `texmf`-releated things from `/var/` (maybe `/var/lib/texmf`)
4. remove `/etc/texmf` too
5. your home directory: `~/.texlive`

I think it's enough.

Answer (score 6):

If you installed TeX Live using `install-tl`: `sudo tlmgr remove --all`.

Answer (score 6):

For Ubuntu 18.04 LTS you can just use

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge texlive tex-common
```

This will delete configuration and/or data files of texlive and tex-common (and it's dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

I would add to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS:

`sudo rm ~/.local/bin/pdftex`

`sudo rm ~/.TinyTeX/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr`

`sudo rm ~/.local/bin/xetex`

`sudo rm ~/.local/bin/luatex`

Those were needed for me when trying to install TinyTeX from scratch using the R package `tinytex`.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Thank you @barbarabeeton!