# Installing TeXLive 2013 side by side on an existing TeXLive 2012

Tags: installing, texlive, ubuntu

`tlmgr` stopped working complaining that it is version 2012 while the repository is 2013. Fine, I need to install TL 2013. So I try and do just that, by following the first link at http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html and downloading, extracting and running: http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz

I now get the following error:

```
./install-tl
Loading http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
=============================================================================
./install-tl: The TeX Live versions of the local installation
and the repository being accessed are not compatible:
      local: 2012
 repository: 2013
Perhaps you need to use a different CTAN mirror?
(For more, see the output of install-tl --help, especially the
 -repository option.  Online via http://tug.org/texlive/doc.)
=============================================================================
```

But this is precisely what I'm trying to solve.. help?

I'm using Ubuntu. `install-tl` is located at `/tmp/install-tl-20130208`

Comment: Since there may be conflicting (duplicate) binaries, you should remove TeX Live 2012 before installing 2013. Sure they can reside side-by-side, but it's easier doing it this way.

Comment: @Werner I wouldn't recommend removing TL 2012. @Yoav: where's your `install-tl` located?

Comment: @egreg I'm using Ubuntu.  install-tl is located at `/tmp/install-tl-20130208`

Comment: What about [this](http://latex-community.org/know-how/latex-distributions/66-latex-distributions-texlive/466-texlive-linux)?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95483/how-to-remove-everything-related-to-tex-live-for-fresh-install-on-ubuntu <--this link will show how to remove everything and this link --> http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu will show you how to install.

Comment: Are you running the installer as root or as an unprivileged user? Did you extend your `$PATH` variable for 2012 or use symlinks? (I.e., what does `which pdflatex` say?)

Comment: Can you check the version of your `install-tl` script? When I installed TL2013 last week, some mirrors at CTAN were still distributing a TL2012 installer, causing this error. A correct TL2013 installer should be dated 201305** or 201306**, if I remember correctly.

Comment: To add @T.Verron  `sha256sum install-tl-unx.tar.gz` at Terminal should match the value inside `install-tl-unx.tar.gz.sha256` file and look the timestamp as well in the mirrors.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I am running as an unprivileged user, and which says `/home/username/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux/pdflatex`

Comment: @T.Verron install-tl version is 20130208. I followed the link mentioned in my post above.  How do I chose a new mirror? How do I know which mirrors are available?

Comment: For me, the link you gave provides a texlive stamped on 24th june. Maybe you should try downloading it again. If you want to try another mirror, check this page : http://ctan.org/mirrors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error appears when you are using an installer for TL2012, while trying to install TL2013. It may happen if some mirrors haven't synced their files yet.

To avoid that, ensure that the file you download is recent enough. Here, your texlive is named `*-20130208`, so it was built on 8th feb 2013.

The [how-to-acquire page](http://www.tug.org/texlive/) tells you that

> [TL2013] was released on 18 June 2013

So you should try to get your hands on an installer timestamped after this date. For me, the [generic download link](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz) gives a recent-enough file, but it can be mirror-dependent. Try redownloading the file, and if it doesn't work, [pick another mirror](http://ctan.org/mirrors).

Comment: Thanks, choosing another mirror worked. (I must say the whole experience with this switch from TL2012 to TL2013 was very unpleasant for someone like me who doesn't really care about versions but is forced to switch in the middle of another project because tlmgr stops working with the new version without warning!)

Comment: @Voav Unless you need to update/add packages, you don't need `tlmgr`. So the usual advice would be not to worry about this in the middle of a project: use the version you already have installed and look at updating only once you finish.

Comment: @Yoav: If you are in the middle of a project you shouldn’t try to update any packages, besides `tlmgr` does not stop working, it just will not offer you any updates which is actually desired in your case.

Comment: @Yoav: Even if you need to add or update a specific packages, chances are that you can do it manually (download the package and copy it in your texmf tree) on your texlive 2012 install.

Comment: At the middle of a project a collaborator added a dependency on the `CJK` package, which I didn't have installed. `tlmgr` *stopped working* by refusing to install this package. Installing it manually was tedious but worked, but turned out to be only partially successful, as it did not install the needed fonts. And fonts are apparently a real nightmare to install manually.  At this point I gave up and installed the new TL2013, which also didn't go very smoothly, as indicated by this question.