# Latex can't find .sty files altough packages are installed -- TexLive, Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: texlive, ubuntu

I just installed TexLive on a i386 Ubuntu 12.04 LTS machine.

Now when I try to compile a TeX file I get following error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `caption.sty' not found.
```

kpsewhich caption.sty gives

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
```

I also tried installing caption with tlmgr but after doing that it doesn't work either.

The last thing I did was copy the contents of the usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ folder to usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/ in hope that it maybe would work.

When i try to compile these are some of the lines that come before the error.

```
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
```

Does anybody know a solution to this?

Comment: Sounds as if you have two tex systems on your PC.

Comment: may be first follow http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95483/how-to-remove-everything-related-to-tex-live-for-fresh-install-on-ubuntu and then go with http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu

Comment: How did you intall `texlive`?

Comment: i did download the install-tl-unx.tar.gz archive, unzipped it and executed the install-tl script in terminal. then it downloaded the whole thing (about 2700 items)

Comment: Did you add lines like this `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux
export PATH
MANPATH=$MANPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf/doc/man
export MANPATH
INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf/doc/info
#export INFOPATH` to your `~/.bashrc` file?

Comment: You might try going to the directory containing the file `caption.sty` and running `sudo ln -s caption.sty /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/. && sudo mktexlsr && sudo texconfig rehash`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

First suggestion would be, Check if the `caption.sty` file is somewhere on the system

```
$ locate caption.sty
```

If it is not installed, most probably the package is not on the basic configuration of `texlive`.

I used the command

```
$ apt-cache search caption | grep tex
```

and found the following packages

```
texlive-latex-recommended - TeX Live: LaTeX recommended packages
texlive-pictures - TeX Live: Graphics, pictures, diagrams
texlive-latex-extra - TeX Live: LaTeX additional packages
telxcc - Teletext closed captioning decoder
```

Install them,

```
$ sudo apt-get -y install texlive-latex-recommended texlive-pictures texlive-latex-extra
```

and try compiling again!

#### Friendly advise

If you have hard disk space to spare, I would recommend to install `texlive-full`, which contains all the packages of the `texlive` version on the repository. So you have less chance to have this type of problems.

### If you install manually

Make sure you add the following lines to your `~/.bashrc` file

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux
export PATH
MANPATH=$MANPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf/doc/man
export MANPATH
INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf/doc/info
export INFOPATH
```

Cheers.

Comment: But if you install `texlive` through the system-packagemanager, you normally don't get `tlmgr`, right? Also many systems have really old texlives.

Comment: @JuriRobl I do have `tlmgr`! (Debian Sid, with `texlive-full` installed through the command line). However, I'm not sure if the old version in the Ubuntu repo has it! :-/

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't get it the last time I installed it on Debian and Ubuntu. It was some time ago, though.

Comment: @Dox: It worked. Although I don't know why.

Comment: @luffer I guess that you had `texlive` installed first from the repo. Therefore, when you installed a new version (manually), it's mandatory to add to the `$PATH` of binaries the new files (this include the newest LaTeX kernel, classes, styles, etc.). Additionally, the new installation has documentation in the for of manual and info pages... the path to those files should be include properly into the `$MANPATH` and `$INFOPATH` variables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just had a last question, How this will change for Tex Studio?

Comment: @L.K. In the post there is nothing related to the editor, but with the LaTeX installation. What do you exactly mean with changes in TexStudio?

Comment: It's counter-intuitive that you need to install other stuff to get texliveonfly to work. Isn't that the package's main selling point?

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to install all the packages of texlive using the command:

```
    sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

Comment: This is a huge amount of stuff, and normally, things should not break if you don't wish to download a full texlive installation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se.  I'm having trouble understanding your last sentence.  Did you mean to say "As on**c**e you get one file file necessary to resolve a missing file **error**, the next **error will** pop out."?  It may be clearer to say "Otherwise, once you resolve one missing dependency, the next one will appear."

Comment: Bubaya, I agree. I tried out the same but then once I started getting dependency issues. I felt it was better to install the entire version than installing each dependency file one by one for Tex.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra` would be a more conservative alternative.

Comment: After seeing millions of files and gigabytes on my Mac, I'm hesitant to ever download a full latex distribution.