# LaTeX not finding .sty files

Tags: texlive, installing, paths

I know a similar question has been asked many times, but I cannot seem to port those answers to my situation.

I have recently installed TeXLive on my Ubuntu 14.04 system.  I did this using the install-tl.zip file from texlive.org.

When I try to compile just the basic TeXLive default article, it crashes on every package, giving me (just to pick the first one):

```
! LaTeX Error: File 'booktabs.sty' not found.
```

But I know booktabs.sty is on my system:

```bash
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty
```

I have the following lines at the end of my .bashrc:

```bash
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH 
export PATH
MANPATH=$MANPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/man
export MANPATH
INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/info
export INFOPATH
```

None of those lines point to the location of any of my .sty files, and I'm not sure what variable should.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome! You should almost certainly remove `MANPATH`. However, that's not the problem here, obviously. Can you compile a document on the command line? If not, what does `which pdflatex` give? (Substitute whichever command you use to compile e.g. `which xelatex` or `which context`.) If you can compile at the command line but not in your editor, which editor do you use?

Comment: Have a look through the answers to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu?s=2|0.0000 to see if you've missed anything. For example, it may be that you have a partial Ubuntu installation of TeX as well as the one  in `/usr/local`, in which case you need to remove it but keep your package manager happy. The answers to the linked question explain the details.

Comment: @cfr  Thanks!  I only have one pdflatex:  which pdflatex
/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex

Comment: So what does `which pdflatex` give? Can you compile on the command line?

Comment: @cfr compiling via command line works using `pdflatex test.tex`  The problem seems to be with TeXWorks.

Comment: You almost certainly have a partial Ubuntu TeX installation as well. You need to get rid of that by following the advice in the posts I linked to above. Then you may need to configure TeXWorks if it doesn't find the binaries automatically. But get rid of the parallel installation first, because TeXWorks may then pick up the right `pdflatex` without help. If not, you can deal with it then.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but I'm not sure about this parallel installation idea.  I only have one pdflatex, only one copy of the various packages, my entire ubuntu installation is very fresh and I've only used install-tl once and never the package manager.  The solution you linked to offers good instructions on how to install LaTeX initially, but I haven't yet found anything about locating and removing another installation.  Can you suggest another test to locate and verify this partial install?

Comment: Sorry for the extended discussion, but i cannot chat.  I see your point about the dual install.  I installed manually to /usr/local/ but TeXworks comes from the software center and thus seems to look at /usr/share.  I'm still trying to parse what the solution might be, but am not clear on that yet.  Do you recommend getting rid of the /usr/local, or the /usr/share?

Comment: Did you install TeXworks after adding those lines to your `.bashrc` (and where did you copy those lines from? the INFO and MAN paths are not, as written, helpful). Although I have never used TeXworks, I wonder: what does 'seems to look at' mean in this context? If `which latex` returns the right thing, what happens if you open an instance of TeXworks from that shell and try to compile a document?

Comment: I'd stick with the `/usr/local` installation. The posts I linked to cover how to keep your package manager happy. When you install TeXWorks, Ubuntu will install a rudimentary TeX Live installation as well, unless you have installed a dummy package to satisfy it.

Comment: @jon - I got those .bashrc lines from the first answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158700/latex-cant-find-sty-files-altough-packages-are-installed-texlive-ubuntu-12?rq=1) I've also run across them in several other posts addressing this question.  I installed TeXworks long before they were added to my .bashrc file, and furthermore, they seemed to have no impact on my issue.  By "seems to look at" I meant that looking at the log file that TeXworks generates, I see many entries listing files located in `/usr/share/`.

Comment: You are setting your $PATH, $INFOPATH, and $MANPATH in different ways is all (and not identical to what you linked to), but it is no big deal. However, they are fundamentally important to the issue: without setting $PATH, e.g., you would not be able to compile from the command line. Did you try what I suggested in my last question in the previous comment? For my editor it would matter if I changed the path assignment. But it [sounds like](http://tug.org/pipermail/texworks/2013q1/005727.html) TeXworks uses $PATH, too, but only after checking the settings in something like 'Preferences'

Comment: @jon.  `which latex` returns `/usr/bin/latex`.  Opening TeXworks via command line then opens an instance which finds the basic .sty files successfully.  Unfortunately, the experiment is flawed, because before running that test, I had already implemented the answer below.  TeXworks now works fine whether opened from command line or from the icon I have in my launcher.  If you can shed some light on why my solution below works, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

I solved my issue by following the answer by @Dox [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158700/latex-cant-find-sty-files-altough-packages-are-installed-texlive-ubuntu-12?rq=1).

Specifically, simply running

`sudo apt-get -y install texlive-latex-recommended texlive-pictures texlive-latex-extra`

fixed my installation.

I confess that I don't entirely understand *why* that worked, and I would love it if someone would explain why.  Using `install-tl.tar.gz` from TeXlive seems to have installed LaTeX into `/usr/local`.  But that does not come with an editor, like TeXworks.  Downloading TeXworks from the ubuntu software center seems to make the editor think that all LaTeX .sty files will be located in in `/usr/share`.  Finally, running the above line of code makes the editor work, yet my `/usr/share/` installation doesn't balloon to ~2 GB.  I still seem to only have one "full" LaTeX installation in `/usr/local` (1.8 GB), while `/usr/share` is very small (100 MB).

I would appreciate any explanation of why this works, or ideas about what is going on behind the scenes of my installation(s?).

Thanks

Comment: I cannot answer why `/usr/share` is so small, but you definitely seem to have two different installations. (A simple test: as we know `which latex` is returning the version installed by `Apt`, then do you have commands like `latex` in [something like] `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex`?) Your basic issue is that you tried to install the editor from Apt, but TeX Live for the official sources; and I imagine Apt-installed versions of TeXworks assume you will install TeX Live from Apt as well. But, originally, you did not.

Comment: You can also check and see which version of a package (e.g., `booktabs`) is being used by adding `\listfiles` to the top of your `.tex` file, compiling the file, and then examining the end of the resulting `.log` file.

Comment: @jon How do you know that the `/usr/bin/latex` is the one from apt?  Putting `\listfiles` at the beginning of my document confirms that it is finding the .sty files in `/usr/share` which is the small installation from apt.  I'm considering removing both and trying to install from `tug.org` again.  Can I just `rm -r /usr/local/texlive` to eliminate that entire install?  I'll use my package manager to remove the `/usr/share/` version.  Thank you for your help.  I've been a user of TeX for a while, but have rarely dipped into the behind the scenes things.  I appreciate your help and patience.

Comment: I know because I've done it both ways over the years. TUG's version installs into the corresponding year directory under `/usr/local/texlive` (see your comment below question; and this is why you had to set your PATH variable). I'd do `rm -rf /usr/local/texlive/2016` if you want to uninstall it. Then reinstall and make sure the PATH is OK; then I'd install the 'fake version' of TeX Live from Apt (see [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html)); then install TeXworks or your editor of choice.