# refcheck package individual installation

Tags: packages, installing

On windows subsystem for linux (WSL) a document containing `usepackage{refcheck}` does not compile and produces with error: `file.tex|| File refcheck.sty not found.`

This suggestion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158700/latex-cant-find-sty-files-altough-packages-are-installed-texlive-ubuntu-12) seems to be to fully install `texlive-full`, but hard disk space is a constraint for me on my machine. Is there a way to specifically install only `refckeck.sty` and other missing packages individually on WSL/Linux machines?

Comment: Download `refcheck.sty` [from CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/refcheck), put it in the same folder as the document you are compiling and see if the error persists, it should go away as latex looks in the same directory as the file being compiled for `.sty` and other files. You could use `wget https://mirror.apps.cam.ac.uk/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/refcheck/refcheck.sty`, that is the link to the `.sty` file

Comment: Do you have vanilla texlive or the one packaged for linux?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I ended up doing `apt-file search "refcheck.sty"` and installing the texlive package that contained this. As of now, it seems to work.

Comment: @Tryer no worries, glad it worked, could you add your comment as an answer and then mark it as complete when the system lets you please? Helps stop questions resurfacing every few months by the `community` bot (:

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved this problem.

Install the `apt-file` application via `sudo apt-get install apt-file`.

Then, run `apt-file search "refcheck.sty"`. This gave:

```
:/mnt/c/Users/Tryer/Desktop$ apt-file search "refcheck.sty"
texlive-latex-extra: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcheck/refcheck.sty
texlive-latex-recommended: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lwarp/lwarp-refcheck.sty
```

Then, I installed the package that contains `refcheck.sty` via:

`sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra`