# How can I update a dummy RPM package to satisfy the dependencies for vim-latex on Fedora 24?

Tags: texlive, installing, texlive-2016, linuxfedora

I have installed TeX Live 2016 on a box running Fedora 24. When using Fedora previously, I installed a dummy `texlive` package which enabled me to install editors etc. without needing to install Fedora's package TeX Live. I am trying to repeat this feat on current Fedora with current TeX Live.

Using Fedora's packages is not an option. (I'd install a different Linux distro rather than do this, but hopefully it won't come to that.)

I suspect the issue is that I do not understand the RPM `.spec` format or `dnf` anywhere near as well as I understand Arch's `PKGBUILD` and `pacman`, for example (and I am hardly exactly knowledgeable about those - but I know where to look ...).

Here's the current version of the `.spec` file, `texlive-dummy-cfr.spec` which I'm using

```spec
Name:    texlive-dummy-cfr
Version: 5.1
Release: 0%{?dist}
Summary: This is a fake TeXLive package
Group:   Applications/Publishing
License: GPLv2 and BSD and Public Domain and LGPLv2+ and GPLv2+ and LPPL
BuildRoot: %(mktemp -ud %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-XXXXXX)                   
Provides: config(texlive)
Provides: kpathsea libkpathsea.so.4()
Provides: tetex tetex-dvips tetex-fonts tetex-latex tex 
Provides: tex(dvips) tex(latex) tex(tex) tex-preview texinfo-tex
Provides: texlive texlive-afm texlive-context texlive-doc texlive-doc-errata
Provides: texlive-dvips texlive-dviutils texlive-east-asian texlive-fonts
Provides: texlive-texmf texlive-latex texlive-utils texlive-xetex          
Provides: texlive-texmf-afm texlive-texmf-context texlive-texmf-doc texlive-texmf-dvips                               
Provides: texlive-texmf-errata texlive-texmf-errata-afm texlive-texmf-errata-context
Provides: texlive-texmf-errata-doc texlive-texmf-errata-dvips texlive-texmf-errata-east-asian
Provides: texlive-texmf-errata-fonts texlive-texmf-errata-latex texlive-texmf-errata-xetex                      
Provides: texlive-texmf-fonts texlive-texmf-latex texlive-texmf-xetex                             
Provides: tetex-IEEEtran tetex-dvipost tetex-elsevier tetex-tex4ht
Provides: tetex-xdvi xdvik
Provides: texlive-base texlive-hyphen-base texlive-kpathsea texlive-kpathsea-bin texlive-lib 
Provides: texlive-kpathsea-doc texlive-lib texlive-xdvi-bin texlive-dvi
Provides: texlive-metafont texlive-metafont-bin texlive-tetex texlive-tetex-bin 
Provides: texlive-texlive.infra() texlive-texlive.infra-bin() 

%description
This was necessary to have a tlmgr-based installation of texlive and all the rpm packages that requires texlive (e.g., a2ps and R-core) still installable.

%prep

%build

%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%doc

%changelog

# vim: set nospell:
```

I then use

```bash
rpmbuild -bb texlive-dummy-cfr.spec
```

This creates a package

```bash
rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/texlive-dummy-cfr-5.1-0.fc24.x86_64.rpm
```

which I then install with `dnf`.

This works fine. Moreover, I have installed Kile successfully, so the dummy package works to some extent.

However, attempting to install `vim-latex` fails:

```bash
Dependencies resolved.
============================================================================================================================================
 Package                         Arch                  Version                                                  Repository             Size
============================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 texlive-kpathsea                noarch                5:svn37193.0-24.fc24.1                                   fedora                153 k
 texlive-lib                     x86_64                5:2015-24.20150728_r37987.fc24                           fedora                429 k
 texlive-xdvi                    noarch                5:svn37078.22.87-24.fc24.1                               fedora                 72 k
 texlive-xdvi-bin                x86_64                5:svn37100.0-24.20150728_r37987.fc24.1                   fedora                317 k
 vim-latex                       noarch                1.8.23-16.20141116.812.gitd0f31c9.fc24                   fedora                216 k

Transaction Summary
============================================================================================================================================
Install  5 Packages

Total download size: 1.2 M
Installed size: 2.7 M
Is this ok [y/N]: N
Operation aborted.
```

Obviously I am doing something wrong. It is not that `dnf` doesn't recognise the fake packages as provided at all:

```bash
for i in texlive-kpathsea texlive-xdvi texlive-xdvi-bin texlive-lib
> do
> dnf provides $i
> done
```

returns

```bash
Last metadata expiration check: 1:41:57 ago on Sat Oct 22 01:40:34 2016.
texlive-dummy-cfr-5.1-0.fc24.x86_64 : This is a fake TeXLive package
Repo        : @System

texlive-kpathsea-5:svn37193.0-24.fc24.1.noarch : Path searching library for TeX-related files
Repo        : fedora

Last metadata expiration check: 1:41:58 ago on Sat Oct 22 01:40:34 2016.
texlive-xdvi-5:svn37078.22.87-24.fc24.1.noarch : A DVI previewer for the X Window System
Repo        : fedora

Last metadata expiration check: 1:41:58 ago on Sat Oct 22 01:40:34 2016.
texlive-dummy-cfr-5.1-0.fc24.x86_64 : This is a fake TeXLive package
Repo        : @System

texlive-xdvi-bin-5:svn37100.0-24.20150728_r37987.fc24.1.x86_64 : Binaries for xdvi
Repo        : fedora

Last metadata expiration check: 1:41:59 ago on Sat Oct 22 01:40:34 2016.
texlive-dummy-cfr-5.1-0.fc24.x86_64 : This is a fake TeXLive package
Repo        : @System

texlive-lib-5:2015-24.20150728_r37987.fc24.i686 : Shared libraries for TeX-related files
Repo        : fedora

texlive-lib-5:2015-24.20150728_r37987.fc24.x86_64 : Shared libraries for TeX-related files
Repo        : fedora
```

I tried adding

```bash
Provides: texlive-kpathsea-5 texlive-lib-5 texlive-xdvi-bin-5 texlive-dvi-5
```

but this still doesn't satisfy the dependencies.

Note that searching for information about this leads me to think that asking on Fedora's forums would not be wise. Previous discussions elicit a response which says roughly: Fedora's packager worked hard to package TeX Live. If anything is missing, it is either not part of TL or not free. If you have a problem with the packages, you should report the issue. You should use the RPMs, in other words, and not want anything else. The people who seem more sympathetic to the project do not, unfortunately, seem to have solutions which might work for me. (REF: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/51707/use-own-texlive-installation/) People here may know less about RPMs, but they are much less likely to reject the whole idea of using upstream's TL as a point of principle!

I am aware that there are various Red Hat dummy packages on CTAN. However, I'm not sure whether any is appropriate here. If any is, I'm assuming it would be the one at https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/texlive/texlive-dummy/EnterpriseLinux-7.

Comment: Is there a need to install `vim-latex` through a Fedora repository rather than [manually](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download&title=Download) or via a vim plugin manager (e.g. [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug)).

Comment: @DaiBowen Not necessarily. However, I'm concerned that I may inadvertently install `texlive-` packages in the future if my dummy doesn't fully convince `dnf` that everything is already installed. (Also, it seems that I must surely be missing something simple and obvious here - how can it not work?!)

Comment: I see, installing `vim-latex` is just the example currently relevant to you but the big issue is "why does my dummy package not satisfy `dnf` that the relevant dependencies on `texlive` are already installed".  Other than noting that `texlive-xdvi` doesn't seem to be listed in your dummy package and `texlive-lib` is listed twice I doubt I can be any help sadly.

Comment: @DaiBowen Thanks. I fiddled a bunch with this and must have lost an `x` somewhere and added an extra `texlive-lib`. I'll correct that, but, yes, you are right about the purpose of my question. I want my dummy to be such that I don't need to worry about installing stuff and inadvertently installing Fedora `texlive` packages, but `dnf` does not seem to appreciate my purpose!