# How to prevent Fedora 28's texlive packager interfering with my freedom to maintain a vanilla installation of TeX Live?

Tags: texlive, installing, linux, linuxfedora

This is essentially a follow-up to earlier questions concerning the procedure for [installing vanilla TeX Live from upstream on a GNU/Linux system](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu?s=2|0.0000).

Part of that process involves the installation of a dummy package, which satisfies the distro's package manager that relevant dependencies are installed when installing programmes which require a TeX installation (e.g. TeX editors, frontends and associated software).

In Arch Linux, this is unproblematic and Debian derivatives seem reasonably pliant also.

However, Fedora is altogether more trouble. Moreover, with the release of Fedora 28, the annoyances have mushroomed into all-out warfare. I am battling `dnf` in a life-and-death struggle entirely of another's making. The packaging is not just exponentially worse. It is ??!! Bonkers. Aggressive. Intrusive. Insidious. Violent. Rude. Insane. Batty. Bananas. Hideous. Eruptive. Disruptive. It is Extreme Packaging taken to its Irrational Logical Conclusion. It is a *reductio ad absurdum* of distros' TeX Live packaging. It is, in a word, Nuts.

Fedora is, moreover, spectacularly unsympathetic to upstream installations. What's wrong with our packages, they ask? The packager worked hard to package the entire TeX Live tree!

The answer to which is: nothing is wrong with them. But this is my machine and I demand the freedom to run the software I want on it. If that means abandoning Fedora, so be it. But this would seem antithetical to the spirit, though not the technical lettering, of the commitments to software freedom which Fedora itself espouses.

Moreover, I like Fedora and I'm hoping that I do not have to leave Fedora in order to exercise freedoms Fedora otherwheres supports.

Originally, it was not hard to build a dummy package to satisfy Fedora. [Things got trickier in Fedora 24](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335281/how-can-i-update-a-dummy-rpm-package-to-satisfy-the-dependencies-for-vim-latex-o) and trickier still in Fedora 26 and 27, but the problem was not entirely unmanageable.

Today, however, I updated from Fedora 26 to Fedora 28 and, lo and behold, the damn thing pulled in piles and piles of `texlive-` packages. There are so many matching packages in Fedora's repos that `dnf` reports finding none if you search just for `texlive` or even something like `texlive-d*`. Apparently, it can't cope with that many results, so concludes there are none whatsoever.

I ended up hacking together a `.spec` file to convince `dnf` to let me remove the unwanted packages, but posting it here goes over SE's character limit, so I've put it at https://pastebin.com/QXFjqW9C instead. The file has  11593 lines,  23249 words and 347644 characters.

This is, clearly, insane. Moreover, the file will need to be continually updated each time Fedora's packager gets a new package from TeX Live. That is, constantly. This is because it seems that some of Fedora's packages include direct dependencies on the lowest level of packaging, so upgrading a system with Kile installed, for example, pulled in specific LaTeX packages - not just some meta package or package group, as I'd have expected.

However, I cannot find a way to avoid this difficulty. A dummy package like this is, I think, the right way to do this, but I can't make it work.

So I've also edited `/etc/dnf.conf`:

```
[main]
gpgcheck=1
installonly_limit=3
clean_requirements_on_remove=True
excludepkgs=texlive-a*,texlive-b*,texlive-c*,texlive-e*,texlive-f*,texlive-g*,texlive-h*,texlive-i*,texlive-j*,texlive-k*,texlive-l*,texlive-m*,texlive-n*,texlive-o*,texlive-p*,texlive-q*,texlive-r*,texlive-s*,texlive-t*,texlive-u*,texlive-v*,texlive-w*,texlive-x*,texlive-y*,texlive-z*,texlive-0*,texlive-1*,texlive-2*,texlive-3*,texlive-4*,texlive-5*,texlive-6*,texlive-7*,texlive-8*,texlive-9*,texlive-da*,texlive-db*,texlive-dc*,texlive-dd*,texlive-de*,texlive-df*,texlive-dg*,texlive-dh*,texlive-di*,texlive-dj*,texlive-dk*,texlive-dl*,texlive-dm*,texlive-dn*,texlive-do*,texlive-dp*,texlive-dq*,texlive-dr*,texlive-ds*,texlive-dt*,texlive-dv*,texlive-dw*,texlive-dx*,texlive-dy*,texlive-dz*,texlive-d0*,texlive-d1*,texlive-d2*,texlive-d3*,texlive-d4*,texlive-d5*,texlive-d6*,texlive-d7*,texlive-d8*,texlive-d9*,texlive-dua*,texlive-dub*,texlive-duc*,texlive-dud*,texlive-due*,texlive-duf*,texlive-dug*,texlive-duh*,texlive-dui*,texlive-duj*,texlive-duk*,texlive-dul*,texlive-dun*,texlive-duo*,texlive-dup*,texlive-duq*,texlive-dur*,texlive-dus*,texlive-dut*,texlive-duu*,texlive-duv*,texlive-duw*,texlive-dux*,texlive-duy*,texlive-duz*,texlive-du0*,texlive-du1*,texlive-du2*,texlive-du3*,texlive-du4*,texlive-du5*,texlive-du6*,texlive-du7*,texlive-du8*,texlive-du9*,texlive-duma*,texlive-dumb*,texlive-dumc*,texlive-dumd*,texlive-dume*,texlive-dumf*,texlive-dumg*,texlive-dumh*,texlive-dumi*,texlive-dumj*,texlive-dumk*,texlive-duml*,texlive-dumn*,texlive-dumo*,texlive-dump*,texlive-dumq*,texlive-dumr*,texlive-dums*,texlive-dumt*,texlive-dumu*,texlive-dumv*,texlive-dumw*,texlive-dumx*,texlive-dumy*,texlive-dumz*,texlive-dum0*,texlive-dum1*,texlive-dum2*,texlive-dum3*,texlive-dum4*,texlive-dum5*,texlive-dum6*,texlive-dum7*,texlive-dum8*,texlive-dum9*,texlive-dumma*,texlive-dummb*,texlive-dummc*,texlive-dummd*,texlive-dumme*,texlive-dummf*,texlive-dummg*,texlive-dummh*,texlive-dummi*,texlive-dummj*,texlive-dummk*,texlive-dumml*,texlive-dummm*,texlive-dummn*,texlive-dummo*,texlive-dummp*,texlive-dummq*,texlive-dummr*,texlive-dumms*,texlive-dummt*,texlive-dummu*,texlive-dummv*,texlive-dummw*,texlive-dummx*,texlive-dummz*,texlive-dumm0*,texlive-dumm1*,texlive-dumm2*,texlive-dumm3*,texlive-dumm4*,texlive-dumm5*,texlive-dumm6*,texlive-dumm7*,texlive-dumm8*,texlive-dumm9*,texlive-dummya*,texlive-dummyb*,texlive-dummyc*,texlive-dummyd*,texlive-dummye*,texlive-dummyf*,texlive-dummyg*,texlive-dummyh*,texlive-dummyi*,texlive-dummyj*,texlive-dummyk*,texlive-dummyl*,texlive-dummym*,texlive-dummyn*,texlive-dummyo*,texlive-dummyp*,texlive-dummyq*,texlive-dummyr*,texlive-dummys*,texlive-dummyt*,texlive-dummyu*,texlive-dummyv*,texlive-dummyw*,texlive-dummyx*,texlive-dummyy*,texlive-dummyz*,texlive-dummy0*,texlive-dummy1*,texlive-dummy2*,texlive-dummy3*,texlive-dummy4*,texlive-dummy5*,texlive-dummy6*,texlive-dummy7*,texlive-dummy8*,texlive-dummy9*
```

Still pretty mad, but a bit less insane and - possibly - slightly more robust than the dummy package. But I'm not sure how wise the approach is or how safe.

`dnf` now tells me that no `texlive*` packages are found either installed or in the repository, though a search for `texlive-dummy-cfr` nonetheless finds my attempt to produce a dummy.

I'd rather not shackle `dnf` like this: I want to stop it installing stuff - not finding it. But only sledge hammers appear to be provided. On the bright side, most of the time `dnf` doesn't acknowledge the existence of any `texlive` packages anyway, so I guess not much is lost for practical purposes.

However, not even all this has eradicated the contamination of the `texlive-` packages entirely. Although the tree is empty, `/usr/share/texmf` is a pretty full hierarchy of empty directories. `dnf` tells me this is provided by `texlive-base`, which is not installed. So I can't even kill the thing completely with both the insane `.spec` and the mad `dnf` sledge hammer.

It is difficult to believe that there is not a cleaner, more elegant way to install Kile than one of these kludges, without abandoning Fedora.

What is the best, most elegant and robust solution on Fedora?

Note: in case it is not obvious, installing Fedora's packages is **not** an option. Getting rid of Fedora **is** an option, but that is my strategy of last resort.

Comment: Could you please remove the rant about Fedora from the question? This is more suited for a personal blog.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301126/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-fedora

Comment: You probably have seen it already, but just to be sure https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/fatka/texlive-dummy/ seems to provide some dummy packages also for Fedora 28, they were last built in 2017. Their `.spec` file is ridiculous, about 10 times the size of yours. (BTW: I do enjoy your writing style, but I can understand if people feel it is a bit too much.)

Comment: @moewe I think cfr's opinion is totally valid, but it just takes too much space.  I'm lazy, I don't want to read all that.

Comment: Nice rant, interesting to read how other Linux-distries move along. I understand how madening this feeling is if the package manager fills the harddisks with gigabytes of useless data. Reminds me on a poem »sorcerer's apprentice«, Goethe. Hey, why don't you give openSuse Leap 15 a try, will be published on May 25th ? I'm on Suse since more than 15 years.

Comment: `sudo dnf copr enable fatka/texlive-dummy` 
`sudo dnf install texlive-dummy`   works for my....Fedora 28 update from 27....

Comment: "In Arch Linux, this is unproblematic" Really, it is? I've recently noticed `texlive-dummy` was gone from the repos. So... I think that is problematic.

Comment: @henry As far as I know `texlive-dummy` was never in the repos and I don't see how it could be. At any rate, I don't believe I ever used it. As far as I can tell, I've always used `texlive-dummy-cfr` i.e. rolled my own. Very easy. In contrast, writing your own `.spec` is fraught with difficulties.