# Load System Fonts in Fedora 28 Texlive 2017* ConTeXt? [to be closed]

Tags: fonts, luatex, texlive, context

The example from `font-sel.mkvi` fails to load system fonts:

```
\definefontfamily [dejavu] [serif] [DejaVu Serif]
\definefontfamily [dejavu] [sans]  [DejaVu Sans]
\definefontfamily [dejavu] [mono]  [DejaVu Sans Mono]
\definefontfamily [dejavu] [math]  [XITS Math] [scale=1.1]

\setupbodyfont[dejavu]

\starttext
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

With these errors:

```
...
selectfont      > The requested font 'DejaVu Serif' has no files for the 'tf' alternative, Latin Modern is used instead.
selectfont      > The requested font 'DejaVu Sans' has no files for the 'tf' alternative, Latin Modern is used instead.
selectfont      > The requested font 'DejaVu Sans Mono' has no files for the 'tf' alternative, Latin Modern is used instead.
...
mkiv lua stats  > loaded fonts: 2 files: lmroman10-regular.otf, xits-math.otf
mkiv lua stats  > font engine: otf 3.029, afm 1.512, tfm 1.000, 4 instances, load time 1.252 seconds
...
```

Same errors for *any* other system fonts. So what to do?

Try running `luaotfload-tool`? It takes a while to create the database, but is able to access all system fonts:

```
$ luaotfload-tool --find='MuseJazz' -F
luaotfload | resolve : Font "MuseJazz" found!
luaotfload | resolve : Resolved file name "/usr/share/fonts/mscore/MuseJazz.ttf"
```

And just for good measure, again:

```
luaotfload-tool --update
```

Unfortunately, still no luck in loading the fonts:

```
export OSFONTDIR="/usr/share/fonts;$HOME/.local/share/fonts;/usr/local/share/fonts;$HOME/.fonts"
context test
```

Then I try:

```
context --generate
```

This runs, but claims to do nothing. I think because it is for single-user installations and it lacks write access to the `/usr/share/tex*` directories. Instead I have to run this:

```
mtxrun --generate
```

This writes to `~/.texlive2017/` but I still can't run the commands the wiki says I'm supposed to run next:

```
$ mtxrun --script fonts generate
mtxrun          | unknown script 'fonts.lua' or 'mtx-fonts.lua'
$ mtxrun --script fonts --list --all --pattern='*'
mtxrun          | unknown script 'fonts.lua' or 'mtx-fonts.lua'
```

OK, lets run anything that has a `--generate` option:

```
$ luatools --generate
mtxrun          | unknown script 'base.lua' or 'mtx-base.lua'
```

Nope... OK, let's switch to the `root` user.

```
$ kpsewhich texmf.cnf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf
```

First edit `texmf.cnf` to replace OSFONTDIR with the value from above. Update the `luaotfload-tool` database as per above. Let's see if `mtxrun` knows about the `fonts` script... No. First run `context --generate` then `mtxrun --generate`. Now there is some apparent success because I can run `mtxrun --script fonts generate`. Unfortunately it appears the generated font database is ignorant of system fonts:

```
$ mtxrun --script fonts --list --all --pattern='*' | egrep -i muse | wc -l
0
```

Even though `mtxrun --generate` only modified the global `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-var/` location rather than `/root/*`, the changes are only accessible to the root user. After switching back to the main user, I still can't run this:

```
$ mtxrun --script fonts generate
mtxrun          | unknown script 'fonts.lua' or 'mtx-fonts.lua'
```

I'm not sure what to try next.

*[*] Texlive on Fedora seems to be a [mix of dates and svn revisions](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/s/texlive)*:

- texlive.noarch 6:2016-52.20160520.fc28
- texlive-base.x86_64 7:20170520-41.fc28
- texlive-collection-context.noarch 6:svn36190.0-52.20160520.fc28
- texlive-collection-luatex.noarch 6:svn39902-52.20160520.fc28
- texlive-context.noarch 7:20170520-41.fc28
- texlive-luatex.x86_64 7:20170520-41.fc28
- texlive-context-title.noarch 6:svn36189.0-52.fc28.2

Comment: luaotfload is irrelevant for context. But beside this I can only suggest to install a current standalone context https://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone.

Comment: If you are the only one to use texlive, I'd suggest a texlive vanilla install on your $HOME. It is more effective than texlive packages on Linux, and AFAIK, installation without root access are recommended since CTAN repos are not fully secured yet. A standalone ConTeXt is an alternative as suggested by Ulrike Fischer while I was typing my comment. Of course, only if you don't use LaTeX.

Comment: The correct arguments to update the font database for ConTeXt are `mtxrun --script fonts --reload`.

Comment: The TeX Live packaging of Fedora is notoriously garbage.  See my comments on this closed question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450184/shell-command-error-when-compiling-with-lualatex-shell-escape-in-fedora-28

Comment: Yeah this should have been a bug report rather than a question here. I'm fine with running standalone ConTeXt.

Comment: Small curiosity, I see `tex/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/xits/XITSMath-Regular.otf` but how do I know which family name so that `\definefontfamily` can load it?

Comment: As you noticed in the question and as I noticed in the other thread linked in a comment above, Fedora uses mutually incompatible, outdated, buggy development versions of TeX Live.  This makes it close to impossible to debug the problem because it has most likely never appeared in a release version.  Therefore I am voting to close this question as off-topic.  Sorry :(