# ! LaTeX Error: File `adjustbox.sty' not found on Fedora 27

Tags: linux, adjustbox, linuxfedora

I was trying to save a Jupyter notebook as a pdf.

I have run

```
sudo dnf install texlive
```

But am getting the error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `adjustbox.sty' not found.
```

Comment: You could also install TeXLive using its own installer/package manager. Linux distributions usually have very outdated LaTeX distributions! See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301126/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-fedora for more details.

Answer (score 5):

Installing the `latexextra` package solved the problem.

```
sudo dnf install texlive-collection-latexextra
```

Comment: This answer works for similar errors while trying to use `\usepackage{tcolorbox}` and `\usepackage[
 usefilenames,
% RMstyle={Text,Semibold},
% SSstyle={Text,Semibold},
 TTstyle={Text,Semibold},
 DefaultFeatures={Ligatures=Common}
]{plex-otf} % Cool font by IBM` packages