# Cannot compile beamer files, Undefined control sequence \languagename

Tags: beamer, babel, translator

I have installed texlive on my Fedora machine per https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301263/28700 and all packages are updated.
I have problem compiling my code.

This minimal example works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

This minimal beamer example works too:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{This is the first slide}
    %Content goes here
  \end{frame}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{This is the second slide}
    \framesubtitle{A bit more information about this}
    %More content goes here
  \end{frame}
% etc
\end{document}
```

I cannot compile this minimal code:

```
% This text is proprietary.
% It's a part of presentation made by myself.
% It may not used commercial.
% The noncommercial use such as private and study is free
% Sep. 2005
% Author: Sascha Frank
% University Freiburg
% www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~frank/


\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Simple Beamer Class}
\author{Sascha Frank}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage} % removing this line allows the document to compile

\frame{\frametitle{Table of contents}\tableofcontents}


\section{Section no.1}
\frame{\frametitle{Title}
Each frame should have a title.
}
\subsection{Subsection no.1.1  }
\frame{
Without title somethink is missing.
}


\section{Section no. 2}
\subsection{Lists I}
\frame{\frametitle{unnumbered lists}
\begin{itemize}
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX
\item Course 2
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX
\item Beamer class
\end{itemize}
}

\frame{\frametitle{lists with pause}
\begin{itemize}
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX \pause
\item Course 2 \pause
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX \pause
\item Beamer class
\end{itemize}
}

\subsection{Lists II}
\frame{\frametitle{numbered lists}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX
\item Course 2
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX
\item Beamer class
\end{enumerate}
}
\frame{\frametitle{numbered lists with pause}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX \pause
\item Course 2 \pause
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX \pause
\item Beamer class
\end{enumerate}
}

\section{Section no.3}
\subsection{Tables}
\frame{\frametitle{Tables}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Date} & \textbf{Instructor} & \textbf{Title} \\
\hline
WS 04/05 & Sascha Frank & First steps with  \LaTeX  \\
\hline
SS 05 & Sascha Frank & \LaTeX \ Course serial \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}


\frame{\frametitle{Tables with pause}
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
A & B & C \\
\pause
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\pause
A & B & C \\
\end{tabular} }


\section{Section no. 4}
\subsection{blocs}
\frame{\frametitle{blocs}

\begin{block}{title of the bloc}
bloc text
\end{block}

\begin{exampleblock}{title of the bloc}
bloc text
\end{exampleblock}


\begin{alertblock}{title of the bloc}
bloc text
\end{alertblock}
}
\end{document}
```

which fails with:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-theorem-dic
tionary-English.dict
Dictionary: translator-theorem-dictionary, Language: English 
) (./Beamer-class-example1.nav)

Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdfauthor' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 14.

! Undefined control sequence.
\trans@languagepath ->\languagename 
                                    ,English
l.17 \frame{\titlepage}
                       
? 
! Emergency stop.
\trans@languagepath ->\languagename 
                                    ,English
l.17 \frame{\titlepage}
                       
End of file on the terminal!
```

The full log is here: https://gist.github.com/183amir/615a9cd2bd5c2027deef3e57b3363555

Could someone tell me what is wrong with my installation? I can compile beamer files on another Debian machine.

Comment: `\title`, `\author` and `\date` should be set before `\begin{document}`. Apart from that, it's a trivial example that should compile easily. Is your TeX Live distribution up to date? Can you compile other (small) documents?

Comment: Thanks, I moved those up. I have investigated this further, only when I add `\date{\today}` the compilation fails. If I do for example `\date{KPT 2004}`, the document compiles fine.