# Installing TeXlive 2015, uninstalling TeXlive 2013

Tags: texlive

I have found many different Q/A regarding installation of various versions of TeXlive and uninstalling ([like this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95502/38874)). To be honest, I might have be a bit lazy.. Will see.

To my best knowledge I am running `Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS` and I have installed TeXlive 2013, `tex --version` gives me `TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)...`. I had troubles running the package `leadsheets` and found some issue thread, that TeXlive 2013 might be missing some features, the exact error is

```
E: /home/quapka/Development/ZpevnikMladez/tex_songs/template.tex:60 "kernel/command-not-defined"! Control sequence \prop_item:Nn undefined. ...ate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { NV }
```

Anyway, I decided to install 2015. But I was lazy and just followed [this guide](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) . But did not do the clean up (since this was the first time I was installing TL2015), but I also did not do anything about the previous version (2013). So, after downloading and running `sudo ./install-tl` I hoped I was done, obviously not. After quick search I've updated `PATH`, like anywhere I could. I am using `zsh`, soo, I changed `PATH` in `/etc/environment, ~/.zshrc, ~/.profile`. Obviously, running `pdflatex` outputs `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)` and not 2015 version.

It seems 2015 is installed correctly, at least `/usr/local/texlive/bin/2015/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex` outputs `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)`
, so hey, it's something. Last note, TL 2013 is not in `/usr/local/texlive/bin/2013/..` the only thing I could find is in `/usr/share/texlive/` (with release notes for 2013 version. In desperate move (it already took me two days, since I lost connection installing TL2015 yesterday) I ran `sudo apt-get remove texlive`, something was removed but not what I hoped.

My question here is. How to *switch* to 2015 version? What should I uninstall (or, I worry, uninstall, remove, remove more, install..).

Disclaimer: I know I should be more careful and etc. But I got used to simply run `sudo apt-get install/update/upgrade` whenever I need to install/update/upgrade something, but all this work because of one package stopped me from being reasonable. If this is dupe of some sort I am happy to delete it and educate myself elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: This is the question you need: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks, I am following the most up-voted answer. Currently I am stuck though, `which tex` does not give me `/opt/texbin` as supposed. Still thanks.

Comment: @cfr I am puzzled since I can't find TeXlive 2013 anywhere. Definitely not in `/usr/loca/texlive/bin`. In `/usr/bin` there are still binaries for 2013, I am confused.. Probably delete this Q and comment under some A in the link?

Comment: Those instructions are for uninstalling if you've installed upstream into `/opt` or `/usr/loacal` etc. You need to use your package manager to remove Ubuntu's packages. Using `apt` or whatever you normally use.