# Can't install fresh Texlive - leftovers from before

Tags: texlive, ubuntu

I tried to follow [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/39314) answer on installing texlive in Ubuntu. I made sure there was nothing left from the system-wide installation

```
sudo apt-get remove texlive
sudo apt-get remove texlive-full
```

before doing that. I went through the installation and added the references

```
 grep -n texbin /etc/environment 
:PATH="/opt/texbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

and there is

```
$ ls /opt/texbin/tex
/opt/texbin/tex
```

However, when I

```
$ which tex
/usr/bin/tex
```

and if I remove that, I actually get an empty return.

I can't remember for the life of me how I installed that `tex` that seems to be lingering around. How can I remove those, or ensure that my freshly installed texlive 2016 takes priority?

Comment: Try [How to remove everything related to TeX Live for fresh install on Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95483/106162)

Comment: Note that the installation of the dummy package is crucial. You must do this unless you use no software from your distro which needs TeX. Usually, you'll at least want an editor or IDE ....

Comment: It could be the problem with permissions. If you get "bash: permission dined: /opt/texbin/tex" after trying to run /opt/texbin/tex, then you can fix that by "chmod +x /opt/texbin/*"