# Freeglut3 not installed, trying to trick ubuntu to thinking TexLive is isntalled

Tags: texlive

Hi I am trying to install latex on ubuntu 16.04 as per the advice below given by Silke

[How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)

I am down to the section of tricking ubuntu into thinking TexLive is installed

when I enter this command

```
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-local:
```

texlive-local depends on freeglut3; however:
  Package freeglut3 is not installed.

in my /tmp/tl-equivs directory

I get this this response

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-local:
 texlive-local depends on freeglut3; however:
 Package freeglut3 is not installed.
```

What can I do to remedy this? Also following this error I get this message

```
dpkg: error processing package texlive-local (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 texlive-local
```

Comment: Do you have a specific reason not to simply install texlive through your package manager? Or, using the command line, `sudo apt-get install texlive`? That will pull in all dependencies automatically. If you really need some specific LaTeX package at a higher version than in Debian/Ubuntu, you can still simply download it from CTAN and save it into your own personal package tree.

Comment: When i installed it through     sudo apt-get install texlive    i was getting "missing packages" error when I tried to compile anything in sublime text 3 using latex tools

Comment: I've given up and wiped everything according to [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95483/how-to-remove-everything-related-to-tex-live-for-fresh-install-on-ubuntu) and did sudo apt-get install texlive-full, and I am still getting a missing package error.

Comment: Is it still the `freeglut3` package that is missing?

Comment: It is a missing Ubuntu package that the pre-built texlive binaries depends on. When dpkg complains like this you can just ask apt-get to fix it via `sudo apt-get install -f`, thus installs any unresolved dependencies

Comment: Remember dpkg cannot resolve dependencies, apt can

Answer (score 2):

You have to install freeglut3. You can install this package as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3
```