# How to remove the tlmgr link from unity search results on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: texlive, installing

I could ask this question on askubuntu or stackoverflow or any other similar site, but I figured some people on TeX.SE will have had the same problem, so here goes.

---

I uninstalled TL2017, following [this much acclaimed checklist](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95502/117274). I did an additional system wide search for `texmf` and `texlive` and some other terms, found some more files, deleted the ones not used any more. I did

```
$ which tlmgr
$ which pdflatex
$ which latex
```

Which all returned nothing, so that's good. Two things remain.

One of them is shown in the picture below. I don't know how to eliminate the handy texlive icon from unity search. Needless to say, when I click it, nothing happens. I don't know where to find the setting that will remove it. I know it's in a directory containing a bunch of files that start with `[desktop]`, but I can't seem to lay my hand on it. If I found the directory, I could just delete the file. It could be so easy!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desktop entries are located in

```
~/.local/share/applications
```

or

```
/usr/share/applications
```

where you can delete the file named `tlmgr.desktop`. I found the path by chance, looking at [gusbrs' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383908/117274) to [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/117274).

Comment: There is also `/usr/share/applications` where it could be located.

Comment: thx for the comment. I'll add this to the answer.