# How to install package so texmaker can use it?

Tags: packages, installing, texmaker

I am trying to install the isomath package. I am following method 3 [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system).
The command `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL` gives me `/usr/local/share/texmf` I put my isomath.sty which I got from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/isomath?lang=en) there and then run `sudo $(which mktexlsr)` which outputs:

```
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVEDIST... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Done.
```

then I tried to restart texmaker but I still get the error `LaTeX Error: File 'isomath.sty' not found.`

Then I tried to do what it says in the README of isomath which says:

> Copy/Move/Link `isomath.sty` to a suitable place in the TDS_ and run
>   `texhash`, or place it in the current working directory (e.g. for
>   testing).

I ran texhash whith this output:

```
texhash: /usr/local/share/texmf: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /var/lib/texmf: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /var/lib/texmf: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /var/lib/texmf: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: Done.
```

As I understand it I did everything right but texmaker is still complaining about not finding isomath, any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: isomath is in texlive and miktex so you shouldn't need to get it from ctan by hand like this? `tlmgr install isomath` ought to install it if it is not installed already.

Comment: it looks like your tex installation is installed as root and you ran texhash as a normal user so nothing got updated. but if installing by hand you should install in a separate directory  not the main directory that is managed by your package manager.

Comment: Quite probably you didn't put isomath.sty in the correct subfolder. But as David already wrote, there should be no need to do this manually anyway.

Comment: Oh ok thanks I will try tlmgr and if that doesnt work I will try texhash with sudo

Comment: None of the ideas worked. I tried tlmgr and I get errors(will follow that lead). But also doing sudo texhash didn't work. I don't know why but maybe my linked answer should be changed then, because it does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up [purging texlive](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95483/how-to-remove-everything-related-to-tex-live-for-fresh-install-on-ubuntu) and then just installing `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` which might take up more space then needed, but I had all the packages I needed.