# Cannot install texlive 2022 - falls back to 2019

Tags: installing, ubuntu, texlive2022

I used to have texlive 2019 installed on my system but I uninstalled it following [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95483/how-to-remove-everything-related-to-tex-live-for-fresh-install-on-ubuntu) instructions in order to upgrade to texlive 2022. For some reason, every time I try to install texlive using `sudo apt install texlive-latex-extra` I get texlive 2019 back, instead of 2022.

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I am using Ubuntu and the command `sudo apt install texlive-latex-extra` on a fresh ubuntu docker image installed texlive 2022 with no problems.

Comment: You are probably using Ubuntu Focal Fossa (aka. 20.04LTS). As usual for Ubuntu packages don't get significant updates after the release, so until you upgrade your distribution you either have to install TeX Live 2019 without `apt` or are stuck with TeX Live 2019.

Comment: More generally: If you want up-to-date software, don't run Ubuntu.

Comment: Ah, you are right. So, do you mean that I cannot install TeX Live 2022 or that I have to install it without `apt`? How can I install it without `apt`?

Comment: See "[How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/80496)" if you want to install TeX Live directly. Then the version is completely independent from your Ubuntu version.

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful!