# Installing a local font on MacTex 2020 on Catalina

Tags: fonts, mactex, macos

[Background: having run out of space and patience, I wiped my system drive and reinstalled Catalina from zero. I am now reinstalling all the applications I still use, one by one.]
I installed MacTex from http://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html and it largely works, but I need to install an additional non-free font, Sabon, for which I have a licence and the relevant files. The notes to myself from a few years back tell me that (given a sabon2.tgz file I prepared at a time, which contains a directory structure with a bunch of Sabon-relevant files) I should create a personal texmf directory at `~/Library/texmf/`.
In there,

```
tar zxvf sabon2.tgz
texhash
updmap --enable Map=psb.map
```

This recipe, which I adapted from something that worked on Linux, had worked successfully for me on mac around 2017. If I changed anything in the meantime, I forgot to note it down. When I tried my own instructions today, however, they didn't work. Texhash said that a bunch of directories were not writable:

```
$ texhash
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-config: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: Done.
```

I got round that by running texhash as sudo, though I'm not sure that's what I was supposed to do. FAQ QM05 at https://tug.org/mactex/faq/faq.html#qm05 says it's not necessary to run texhash when adding files to ~/Library/texmf, so I presume this step has become unnecessary in 2020. OK, so we move on. Next failure:

```
$ updmap --enable Map=psb.map
updmap [ERROR]: Either -sys or -user mode is required.
updmap [ERROR]: In nearly all cases you should use updmap -sys.
updmap [ERROR]: For special cases see https://tug.org/texlive/scripts-sys-user.html
```

Following the error message I add -sys...

```
$ updmap -sys --enable Map=psb.map
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap: can't write to /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg: Permission denied at /Library/TeX/texbin/updmap line 1589.
```

...but again a permission error. Here too, I add sudo and retry:

```
$ sudo updmap -sys --enable Map=psb.map
updmap [WARNING]: resetting $HOME value (was /Users/XXX) to root's actual home (/var/root).
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
Creating new config file /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
dvips output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap"
pdftex output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap"
dvipdfmx output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap"
updmap [ERROR]: The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
updmap [ERROR]:     psb.map (in /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [ERROR]: Did you run mktexlsr?

    You can disable non-existent map entries using the option
      --syncwithtrees.
```

I imagine the reason why updmap couldn't find psb.map is because psb.map is in my user's ~/Library/texmf, but if I run updmap as root then it's not searching that place. On the other hand, if I run it as me, it can't update the file.

Thanks to this question, [Local font installation problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55881/local-font-installation-problems), I found out I could write updmap-sys without space, and that would work without sudo:

```
$ updmap-sys --enable Map=psb.map
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.
updmap: Updating ls-R files.
```

And that file now contained the single line "Map psb.map":

```
$ cat /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
Map psb.map
```

However, on compiling a known-good tex file that used Sabon, I got

```
$ pdflatex test.tex 
...
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+264/600 --dpi 864 psbb8r
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for psbb8r.
mktexpk: perhaps psbb8r is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
(see the transcript file for additional information)
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file psbb8r): Font psbb8r at 864 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Why does it want to create any bitmap fonts in the first place? I just want vector fonts anyway. It's not the 20th century any more.

What am I missing and what should I be doing instead?

Comment: I don’t have a Mac to test this on. However, from the messages you’re getting, it does not seem to be searching your `~/Library/texmf`. You should be able to put the files in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`.

Comment: @Davislor: QM 05 FAQ of mactex (https://tug.org/mactex/faq/faq.html#qm05): "Where do I put my personal additions to the texmf tree? AM.05: They go in ~/Library/texmf". So I'm doing what they're telling me to do, and am slightly wary of putting things elsewhere instead...

Comment: Yeah, but font map files are an exception. The `updmap-sys` command doesn't search your `$TEXMFHOME` directory, and `updmap-usr` is a trap. You never want to run it, because it will override your system map instead of supplementing it.

Comment: You could also run `updmap-sys --force --cnffile=~/Library/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg`, though.

Comment: At least, that’s how it works on other OSes. I don’t know the quirks of MacTeX.

Comment: @Davislor: there is no web2c directory under ~/Library/texmf. So I tried `updmap-sys --force --cnffile=/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg` but got `updmap: Directory "/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap" isn't writable:  at /Library/TeX/texbin/updmap line 1463.`. Living dangerously I retried it with sudo but got `updmap [ERROR]: The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
updmap [ERROR]:  psb.map (in /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [ERROR]: Did you run mktexlsr?`. I am more and more confused.

Comment: You just manually selected the default map file. `psb.map` is not in a directory that was being searched.The simplest solution is probably to put your Sabon files in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`.

Comment: @Davislor: OK, I bit the bullet and untarred my bundle in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` as you suggested (with some trepidation because there was already stuff there, so it was not an operation I'd be able to undo easily). I then did (with some trial and error) `sudo mktexlsr` and `sudo updmap-sys --force --cnffile=/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg` and now it properly compiles my test document. Thanks!

Comment: Could it be those protection things that forbid random applications to write everywhere? See [SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really) and [control access](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchld5a35146/mac).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some discussion in the comments, the best solution was to unpack the files in your `TEXMFLOCAL` directory (Here, `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`), instead of `TEXMFHOME` (Here, `~/Library/texmf`).

The MacTeX FAQ recommands putting local files in the latter, but 8-bit font maps are an exception.  You never want to run `updmap` in user mode.  It’s a trap that will override your system font maps instead of supplementing them, and get more and more out of date as you update your system tree.  However, `updmap-sys` does not search `TEXMFHOME`.

Comment: Thanks for wrapping up the discussion into an answer I can now accept.

Comment: I always recommend TEXMFLOCAL. TherE is a Preference setting in TeX Live Utility, a front end for to tlmgr and more, that will automatically run updmap-usr when you use it to do you TeX Live updates.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Does that work with MacTeX?

Comment: @HerbSchulz I almost always use `TEXMFLOCAL` as well

Comment: @Davislor : that works with TeX Live Utility which is a front end for tlmgr and Mac Only. It works with the TeX Live installed with MacTeX or directly from TUG.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Feel free to post that as an alternative answer!