# Installing Mathematica Fonts in MikTeX

Tags: fonts, miktex, installing, wolfram-mathematica

I would like to use Mathematica fonts with pdfLaTex in Miktex, but I'm having trouble installing them.

I have only found guides as to how to install them in TexLive and I don't know how to alter the procedure to fit my case.

I found the latest fonts here http://support.wolfram.com/kb/10427 and this old post [How use Mathematica fonts with LaTeX - which method?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51704/how-use-mathematica-fonts-with-latex-which-method/51708#51708) but I cannot use any of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after one day of craziness I could make it work following a modified version of the instructions found [here](http://blog.spitzenpfeil.org/wordpress/2011/02/07/getting-mathematica-fonts-to-work-with-pdflatex/).

I will assume you have MiKTeX installed in a folder called "MiKTeK"

- Download this [package](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jtavn8wjfjhchkb/mathematica.7z?dl=0) (it's a modified version of the one I found in the page linked above).
- Copy ‘texmf/dvips/config/wolfram.map’ to ‘MiKTeK/fonts/map/dvips/wolfram/’ – create the folders if missing
- Copy ‘texmf/pdftex/config/pdfwolfram.map’ to ‘MiKTeK/fonts/map/pdftex/wolfram/’
- Copy all subfolders from ‘texmf/fonts’ (afm/wolfram/mma …) to the corresponding folders in ‘MiKTeK/fonts/’
- Copy all files from ‘tfm/public/mma’ in ‘MiKTeK/fonts/tfm/public/mma’
- Copy the folder ‘mma’ to ‘MiKTeK/source/latex/mma’
- Copy the folder ‘texmf/tex/latex/wolfram’ to ‘MiKTeX/tex/latex/wolfram’
- Enable the map files by opening ‘MiKTeX/miktex/config/updmap.cfg’ with some text editor and adding the line: "Map wolfram.map"
- Open the MiXTeX setting as an administrator (from start menu) and hit "Refresh FNDB".

All the fonts now work for me.

Comment: does the package link still work?