# Mathematica fonts with MikTeX

Tags: fonts, miktex, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to use the Mathematica fonts that the [mathalfa](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathalfa) package is said to support. But when I add `\usepackage[cal=mma]{mathalfa}` I get the following error:

```
Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following reason: 
The mmamcal source file could not be found. 
[...]
hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4) Couldn't open `mmamc.cfg'
```

I gather this is an error caused since the Mathematica fonts are missing. And I have been trying to install them manually, and failed. Where can I find them? Older questions only provide dead links ([Installing Mathematica Fonts in MikTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223131/installing-mathematica-fonts-in-miktex)). And how do I install them properly so that MiKTeX finds the fonts?

I am using TeXstudio on a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding Mathematica (the software) with mathematical fonts.

Comment: I have no idea where you can find the font -- but you could ask the author of mathalfa. He seem to have had at some time the necessary files (as the links in the documentation are dead they should be corrected anyway).

Comment: In earlier versions of Mathematica one got some sets of PostScript fonts, but that does not seem to be the case anymore. They probably changed the font format. In any case I think they were never free (but ships with Mathematica). Maybe one can get more information from mathematica.stackexchange.com?