# How do I get the mathalpha package fonts working?

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

The `mathalpha` packages provides several fonts for math typesetting, for example script and fraktur fonts. However, I tried using them and it does not work. I can only use the euler fraktur font for example:

```
\usepackage[frak = euler]{mathalpha}
% ...
\mathfrak{F}
```

works, but `frak = mma` for the mathematica font does not. The error message in TeXstudio reads

> Font U/mmamfrak/m/n/10.95=mmamfrak at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. \end{align}

and the TeXstudio log reads

> Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\...\miktex-makemf.log Couldn't open `mmamfr.cfg' hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4)

and the logfile repeatedly reads

> 2020-08-01 10:42:13,976+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The mmamfrak source file could not be found.
> 2020-08-01 10:42:13,977+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The mmamfrak source file could not be found.
> 2020-08-01 10:42:13,977+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Info:
> 2020-08-01 10:42:13,977+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Source:
> 2020-08-01 10:42:13,977+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Line: 0

I don't have mathematica installed not any of the other fonts explicitly. Could this be the problem? How do I install these fonts if they are missing? (And if they are easily available)

I am using MikTeX version 2.9 and try to compile using PdfLaTeX

Comment: I also ran into this issue...has there been a solution found? I run in Overleaf, and using {mathalpha} on [scr=boondoxo] and [cal=euler] both work, but not the [frak=mma] or [frak=lucida]. Using [frak=euler] worked somewhat, i.e. the first few times I called \mathfrak it was ok but then the next few times it got "Too many math alphabets in version normal" error...which went away when I deleted [frak=euler] from the {mathalpha} package line. Even more mysteriously even after I deleted [frak=euler], \mathfrak was in euler font! Again, all other \cal and \scr fonts work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation of `MATHALPHA`, `AKA MATHALFA PACKAGE` on this link https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf I add some important screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

An important link of TeX.SE:

[How to use fonts (the ones listed in mathalfa documentation) in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384937/how-to-use-fonts-the-ones-listed-in-mathalfa-documentation-in-math-mode/384959)

You can see that in this link

http://mirror.neu.edu.cn/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mathalfa/mathalfa.tex

there is the `file.tex` of the package. Using [Papeeria](https://www.papeeria.com/), to compile, I have tried a piece of code and I have not `frak=mma` fonts. You can compare with the documentation at page 7.

[image]

At this link `https://ctan.org/pkg/mathematica` you can download the [Mathematica3.0 fonts](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/psfonts/Mathematica3.0.zip) and in this link [How use Mathematica fonts with LaTeX - which method?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51704/how-use-mathematica-fonts-with-latex-which-method) there are the instructions.

### ADDENDUM:

In this [link](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/3200/) you can find also the `wolfram.map`; exactly they are named `wrifnt1_0_3` in the [link](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/3200/wrifnt1_0_3.zip?file_id=2079).

[image]

Comment: The mma fonts are not typeset as fraktur fonts... Same for mt and lucida

Comment: @HerpDerpington In fact :-)...See these links https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349628/mathematica-fonts-with-miktex; https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51704/how-use-mathematica-fonts-with-latex-which-method

Comment: From what I have seen, the missing files should be in the `mathematica` package, but installing that package does not solve the problem, even after updating the font map...

Comment: If I could provide a .log file or something else that can help you, I would appreciate it so that other users can respond to you.

Comment: The error is unchanged... "Couldn't open 'mmamfr.cfg' ..." from miktex-makemf

Comment: The logged error message is identical.

Comment: @HerpDerpington Uhmmm...Have you seen this link, if your procedure to install font is it correct? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419957/latest-miktex-suggestions-on-how-to-install-new-fonts-using-the-miktex-console

Comment: I don't really see how I could apply that to my problem, since I assume the `mathematica` package would install the fonts automatically;  I don't known if there is any directory where I could find the actual files I need for the procedure described in the link. Did I perhaps miss some step?

Comment: `mathematica` in my humble opinion is not in the distribution of MikTeX, hence you should download it and follow Ulrike's procedure which is the best answer. My following procedure is a bit more complex.

Comment: Then I don't see how the zip files I downloaded at `https://ctan.org/pkg/mathematica` have anything to do with the description... There is no wolfram.map file inside the archive, only "mma.map". Installing `mathematica` from the MikTeX Console creates the same files in the corresponding directories as the instruction tells me to copy!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111333/discussion-between-sebastiano-and-herpderpington).

Comment: I have made several attempts to install the fonts according to the answers provided in the other posts, but none solve the problem. I fear that the underlying problem is some different. For example I cannot find this "mmamfr.cfg" file anywhere on my disk (maybe it's a temporary file or something similar...)