# miktex-makemf does not find .cfg or metric file for font - where do I get these?

Tags: fonts, miktex2.9, installing-fonts, otftotfm

I tried to manually install a font from a .ttf file, let's call it *XYZ*, in pdfLaTeX (LuaLatex etc are not an option; I tried that and I could not get it working because it caused to much problems with packages and messed up all other fonts).

I followed the instructions given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1472). I created the `tex` and `fonts` directory for the texmf tree using the [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux), as I am working on Windows 10. `autoinst` created a directory `autoinst_output` containing the tree which I copied to a user defined texmf directory. Then I added this directory to MikTeX via the MikTeX Console (it is listed with Purposes = Generic and Attributes = User). There seems to be no .cfg file anywhere inside this tree. 
During the installation I also found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88424) helpful. I updated the file name database and the font map files countless of times in different orders.

One of the questions also mentions [this website](http://www.radamir.com/tex/ttf-tex.htm). It says that one can test if a font works via the cmd terminal. I typed:

```
$ tex testfont
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (MiKTeX 20.6.29)

("... testfont.tex location ...")
Name of the font to test = XYZ
Running miktex-makemf.exe...

Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed.

The log file hopfully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
... path to logfile ...
Couldn't open `XYZ.cfg'


hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4)

Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed.

The log file hopfully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
... path to logfile ...

! Font \testfont=XYZ not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again>
... TeX code of the testfont.tex file ...
```

The logfile reads

> FATAL miktex-makemf - No creation rule for font XYZ.
> FATAL miktex-makemf - No creation rule for font XYZ.
> FATAL miktex-makemf - Info:
> FATAL miktex-makemf - Source:
> FATAL miktex-makemf - Line: 0

This also seems to be related to [this question and answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75166). If I go to the directory texmf-root\tfm\lcdftools\*XYZ* if find a lot of files like

> *XYZ*-lf-ly1.tfm 
> ... 
> *XYZ*-tlf-ly1.tfm 
> *etc...*

how are these related to the problem?

Note that this might also resolve [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/556947) I asked.

Comment: If the name of the tfm is XYZ-lf-ly1.tfm you should test XYZ-lf-ly1 and not XYZ. Beside this: switching to lualatex and creating a font for pdflatex are both not easy if you are new to it, and you can run into errors with both. But the first is much easier than the second. You choose the harder route.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That works. Do you know what those suffixes `lf-ly1` etc stand for? If so, you can write an answer to the post and I'll accept it.