# Can't "detexify" this symbol for the exponential function

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I saw on [The Wolfram Research](http://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFunctions/HeavisideTheta/07/01/01/0001/) site,

[image]

As you can see it is something like a `$\mathbb{e}$`, except that using `$\mathbb{e}$` would not produce output at all.

Also the imaginary unit has the same style, can someone provide a way to reproduce it in LaTeX?

EDIT:

I'm adding two more detailed images in the hope that someone will implement a math font for these symbols

[image][image]

Comment: stix fonts have these characters so you can use the stix package. The question was asked (about d) just the other day so this will be a duplicate if I can find the old question...

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, but I don't think the provided answer gives me the desired output... The style in the marked question are slightly different, even, for example, on the fact that on Wolfram it appears to be an italic font, while in the answers they're not... I hope I could get a better answer!

Comment: Also the exponential symbol does appear much different...

Comment: Sorry my followup comment was nonsense, stix fonts have these characters (as does unicode) I added an answe

Comment: you can also use the wolfram font from mathematica in tex eg https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51704/how-use-mathematica-fonts-with-latex-which-method

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stix}

\begin{document}


$\mathbbit{e} \neq e \neq \mathbb{e} \neq \mathbf{e} \neq \mathbfit{e}$


$\mathbbit{i} \neq e \neq \mathbb{i} \neq \mathbf{i} \neq \mathbfit{i}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer David, but I still don't get the desired results. As a matter of facts, the symbols you showed above are in another font than the standard Computer Modern, what I actually would like is that the `e` anche the `i` maintain their shape, but with that fancy white space inside their body... Do you think it would be possible?

Comment: @opisthofulax no basically that's not possible while using the character as a font, using pstricks for some fonts you can get a reasonable outline and then separately draw and fill the outline but this is turning the font glyph into a graphic.